# Can't import Compose Navigation

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm started a new project using the pattern "Empty Compose Activity", in my MainActivity.kt I tried to implement the navigation, but when I tried to import has a error saying "Unresolved reference: navigation".

My MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.formsapp

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.formsapp.ui.theme.FormsAppTheme
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            FormsAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    ScreenMain()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScreenMain(){
    val navController=remeberNavController()
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(text = "Hello $name!")
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    FormsAppTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

My build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.formsapp'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.formsapp"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"
}
```

A way to can use the navigation for my Koltin with Jetpack app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I check your gradle you already added

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3"
```

now try to type just **reme** where you want to use `remeberNavController()` then it will show you auto suggestion as below screen shots.

same problem I face I solve it by running gradle sync and then type just **reme** and I am able to use it.

Hope it will work for you!!

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Pratik Fagadiya to update it.

Comment: Thanks man, I execute the graddle sync and the library now it's available.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this navigation library in build.gradle file then you will able to use `remeberNavController()`

```
 def nav_version = "2.5.3"

 implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version")
```